# Visually representing high dimensional point clusters

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computer-science

I have a lot of data consisting of points in $\mathbb{R}^{100}$. I would like to represent these points in two or three dimensions, in such a way that roughly preserves the distances: i.e., if a group of points forms a cluster in $\mathbb{R}^{100}$, they will form a cluster in the visual representation; if they are far apart, they will be far apart in the visual representation. Of course, the picture cannot be perfect, but I want something that provides a nice illustration for the casual observer. What are some common ways to do this?

Edit: I am not fussy; even an algorithm that inputs many points and their pairwise distances and outputs a visual representation would suffice.

Also: [here](https://www.music-map.com/pink+floyd.html) is an example of the type of picture I wish to generate.

Comment: A very interesting question. I'm not sure how to approach it

Comment: Do you know about "projection pursuit" and "ggobi" ?  (Both topics have wikipedia entries.)

Comment: Those do seem relevant to my my problem, but more sophisticated then what I had hoped for here.

Comment: Also, for anyone interested, [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) seems to be related.

Comment: It reminds me [Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma).